# Gradient inequality in Morrey's and Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality proofs

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I'm approaching for the first time functional analysis and in general "advanced math". In the book "*Lecture Notes on Functional Analysis*" by A. Bressan, in the Sobolev space chapter, I get stuck in two inequalities involving $\nabla u$. $$$$ **1)** In the proof of **Morrey's inequality**: be $u \in C^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\cap W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$; in the proof, the following set of coordinates is defined: $(r,\xi)=(r,\xi_{2}...\xi_{n}) \in \left[0,\rho \right] \times  B_{1}$, with $B_{\rho}:=\left( x=(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n});x_{1}=\rho,  \ \sum_{i=2}^{n} \ x^2_{i}\leq \rho^{2}\right)  $; to this system of coordinates, the point $x(r, \xi)=(r,r \xi)$ is associated (x belongs to a cone), moreover define $U(r,\xi)=u(r,r\xi)$. Here I got stuck (citing the text): since $|\xi|\leq 1$ the directional derivative of $u$ in the direction of the vector $(1,\xi_{2},\xi_{3},...,\xi_{n})$ is estimated by $$\left| \frac{\partial }{\partial r} U(r,\xi)\right|=\left| u_{x_{1}}+\sum_{i=2}^{n}\xi_{i}u_{x_{i}} \right| \leq 2|\nabla u(r,\xi)|.$$
$$  $$ **2)** In the proof of **Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality**:  be $f \in C^{1}_{c}\left( \mathbb{R}^{n} \right)$ , I got stuck in the following inequality: $$ \prod _{i=1}^{n} \left( \int _{-\infty}^{\infty}...\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} \left | D _{ x _{i}} dx _{1} dx _{2}... dx _{n}   \right | \right) ^{1/(n-1)} \leq \left ( \int _{\mathbb{R}^{n}}^{} |\nabla f|dx  \right )^{n/(n-1)} $$ $$$$ It seems to me that I miss something becouse in the book it appears that such inequalities involving $\nabla u$ and $ \nabla f $ are so straightforward; I probalby lack the knowledge of some identity or inequality, perhaps from calculus. Could anyone give me some hints? Thank you for your kindness, I apologize if it might be trivial, but I’m a rookie!

Comment: It appears that something is wrong with the formatting of the second inequality. Or perhaps the notation $D_{x_idx_1\ldots dx_n}$ is defined somewhere. Can you clarify it please?

Comment: Oh! yes, there is a typing error, I'll edit the question, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is as timur said for the first one - \begin{align}
   \left| \frac{\partial }{\partial r} U\right|\overset{\substack{chain\\rule\\{\phantom{x}}\\}}=\left| u_{x_{1}}+\sum_{i=2}^{n}\xi_{i}u_{x_{i}} \right| \overset{\triangle ineq.}\le  |u_{x_{1}}|+\sum_{i=2}^{n}|\xi_{i}||u_{x_{i}}|  \overset{C-S}\le |u_{x_{1}}|+\sqrt{\sum_{i=2}^{n}|\xi_{i}|^2 } \sqrt{\sum_{i=2}^{n}|u_{x_{i}}|^2 } 
   \end{align} Now observe that \begin{align}|u_{x_1}| &\le \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n |u_{x_k}|^2} = |\nabla u|,\tag{GradientBound}\label{X}\\ \sqrt{\sum_{i=2}^{n}|\xi_{i}|^2 } &\le 1, \\
   \sqrt{\sum_{k=2}^n |u_{x_k}|^2} &\le \sqrt{\sum_{k=\color{red}1}^n |u_{x_k}|^2}=|\nabla u|,\end{align}
   which gives
   $ \left| \frac{\partial }{\partial r} U\right| \le 2|\nabla u|$ as claimed.
2. I can confidently interpret $\prod _{i=1}^{n} \left( \int _{-\infty}^{\infty}...\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} \left | D _{ x _{i} dx _{1} dx _{2}... dx _{n}  } \right | \right) ^{1/(n-1)} \leq \left ( \int _{\mathbb{R}^{n}}^{} |\nabla f|dx  \right )^{n/(n-1)}$ as this part of the proof of the Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev inequality:
   $$\prod _{i=1}^{n} \left( \int _{-\infty}^{\infty}\dots\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} | D_{ x _{i}}f| dx _{1} dx _{2}\dots  dx _{n}    \right) ^{1/(n-1)} \leq \left ( \int _{\mathbb{R}^{n}}^{} |\nabla f|dx  \right )^{n/(n-1)}$$ Indeed, this is what page 171 of Bressan's book says. This is also the proof in Evans.
3. To prove this, note that there is a product of $n$ terms on the left hand side, and there is an $n$ power on the left. This hints  that there may be an estimate that does not depend on which of the $n$ terms you are estimating. That is, it is enough to show that for each $i=1,2,\dots,n$,

$$ \left( \int _{-\infty}^{\infty}\dots\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} | D_{ x _{i}}f| dx _{1} dx _{2}\dots  dx _{n} \right)^{1/(n-1) } \le \left(\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}\dots\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} |\nabla f| dx_1dx_2\dots dx_n\right)^{1/(n-1)}$$
and this directly follows from the line marked $\eqref{X}$ above.

Comment: Oh thak you a lot!!! very clear explanations! I will edit the anwer because in Bressan, the $\xi$ vector strart with the index 2. Obviously the explanation remain still valid!

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice! I will change it

Answer (score 2):

The first one is Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$
\big|\sum_{i=2}^n\xi_iu_{x_i}\big|
\leq
\big(\sum_{i=2}^n\xi_i^2\big)^{\frac12}
\big(\sum_{i=2}^n|u_{x_i}|^2\big)^{\frac12}
\leq|\xi||\nabla u|
\leq|\nabla u|.
$$

Comment: Oh! how did I not see it?!. Thank a lot!!!